# Using "extern" command in c for sharing a variable

Tags: c, header, extern

I have the following codes:

(1) extern_test.h:

```
extern int give_something;
```

(2) extern_test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "extern_test.h"
int give_something = 10;
```

(3) extern_test2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "extern_test.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%i\n", give_something);
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I compile extern_test2.c on terminal, it says "undefined reference to 'give_something'".... Please help why this doesn't work..

Comment: show us your makefile / command line.

Comment: Are you linking it with extern_test.c? Without that the linker won't know where give_something is defined. As far as it is concerned extern_test.c doesn't exist. So give_something is never defined.

Comment: This is what I get:

~$ gcc extern_test2.c -o extern_test2 ----> gives ----->

/tmp/ccydzDba.o: In function `main':
extern_test2.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `give_something'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @BenjyKessler How can I link with extern_test.c?

Comment: See https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "Undefined Reference" means that the code is *written* fine, but once all the different files are compiled and it's time to link them together, one of the files doesn't have the thing you're looking for (in this case, `give_something`). This is called a linker error.

The problem is most likely that you aren't using the correct command line for the compiler - you're attempting to compile `extern_test.c` and `extern_test2.c` into two separate binaries. Thus, when you compile `extern_test.c` it works fine, but when you attempt to compile `extern_test2.c` it can't find the variable because it was declared in `extern_test.c`.

Assuming you're using g++, use this command line:

```
g++ extern_test.c extern_test2.c
```

Notice how they are both compiled together. There are fancier commands that allow you to compile each one individually into an *object file*, then *link* them all together afterward with a third command, but that isn't necessary here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about linking.. Since I'm using gcc:

gcc extern_test.c extern_test2.c -o extern_program

and then ./exterm_program  . This worked. Thank a lot!

Comment: Although `g++` would compile this, `gcc` should be used; otherwise the files are treated as `C++`.